# Switch to use in high g-force environment?

Tags: switches, design, physics

I need an on/off type switch (spst) on a device that will be subject to high, continuous centrifugal force loads (500-1000G or 5000-10000 m/s2)).
Will your everyday, off-the-shelf switch handle this?

Are there certain types of switch (sliding, toggle, push on/off) that will likely handle the forces better?  It seems not many datasheets have such a rating.

I'm interested in both quantitative and/or experienced-based answers (i.e. "here's a datasheet" or "well, I've used this  in this situation before").  EE Stackexchange seemed like the best place to ask this.

EDIT: The switch will be used to turn on/off a wireless data device.  The switch will effectively just be pulling an enable pin high, so it's handling 3.3 to 5V, 1-10mA.  My concern rests mostly with undesired switching on/off due to the forces involved.  Am I unduly concerned?

EDIT: I talked with a friend, and she happens to be involved in rocketry - another electronics in high-G situation (although 50-100G are more typical).  She mentioned that for switches, Rotary, screw, or just twisting the wires together are considered reliable.

I'll probably go with a screw switch unless someone suggests something else.

Comment: Just a dry logic switch? And in what direction is the acceleration relative to the mounting plane?

Comment: would you consider a ROTARY switch?

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes, it won't be passing much current.  Effectively just bringing a pin high.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf If they handle the forces well, maybe.  Is that your experience? They seem to be a bit bulky, generally, but if they work...

Comment: Use a solid state relay. No mechanics involved. But you should define a spec bu editin your question. *"Yes, it won't be passing much current."* 5 A isn't mucf if you use to work with tens of kA... I think you mean mA, otherwise I didnt suggest a solid state, but still.

Comment: @Huisman Solid state relay how?  I need an on/off, user-interactable switch.  Do you mean some kind of solid state timer?  Valid point about the current, though.  I'm dealing with 5V, probably 1-10mA.  I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I missed it should be user-interactable... What are the environmental conditions? Maybe a simple (two plate) touch sensor may work?

Comment: Who will switch this switch in 500G enwironment? Your arm will weight 200kg and you wont be able to move it (if you are still alive).

Comment: This is a data acquisition device built around a rotating shaft.  While it is being switched, it is under no load.  I'm concerned about what might happen to the switch (forces turn it off, on, move the internal contacts, etc) while under load.

Comment: Maybe you can save the state of the switch before it starts rotating?

Comment: @WesleyLee Maybe... I've also considered a g-switch that will just turn it on once it starts rotating, but...  really all I need is a contact that will guaranteed stay closed under the forces involved.

Comment: @IronEagle *stay closed or open. It's easy to ensure it stays closed: replace with direct connection.

Comment: Mounting the switch such that all moving parts move perpendicular to the radius of rotation seems like a reasonable option. That way the forces will all be directed perpendicular to the switch's moving parts. Rotary switches would probably make this easy, or right-angle slide switches.